# Is `pnpify --sdk vscode` needed if you aren't using PnP with Yarn 2?

Tags: visual-studio-code, yarnpkg-v2

We are slowly legging into using Yarn 2 and have opted to not use the Plug-n-Play feature.

[Disable PnP Instructions](https://yarnpkg.com/api/modules/plugin_node_modules.html)

```js
// .yarnrc.yml file

yarnPath: '.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs'
nodeLinker: node-modules
```

We also use VS Code and the Yarn 2 migration guide states:

- If you're using VSCode (or some other IDE with Intellisense-like feature):

  - Run yarn dlx @yarnpkg/pnpify --sdk vscode to add TypeScript support (cf Editor SDKs for more details)
  - Commit the changes if you want to avoid asking your contributors to run this step, or gitignore them otherwise
  - Don't forget to switch the TypeScript version to "workspace" in VSCode

**Is this necessary if PnP is disabled? I assume not but wanted to check.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not necessary with `node-modules` linker

Comment: Thanks. I messed around with it this weekend and discovered this was the case. 
It makes sense. If you aren't using the PnP features then you don't need to tell vscode how to deal with the new way of caching.